# Turing image that hovers transparent into an image button

Tags: html, css

so i have created an image button and i gave it a transparent black hover attribute. For some reason the image is not a "button" anymore, but it still has the hover effect. Is there any way that i can keep the button attribute while still having the color?

http://jsfiddle.net/cp14rbpa/1/

What i am thinking is that the transparent hover overlay overrides the image button attribute. I am not sure if that is the problem though.

```
<body>
<div class="image">
<a href="#"><input type="image" src="img/testor.jpg" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit"     id="saveForm" /></a> 
</div>
</body>

.image {
    position:relative;
    width:726px;
    height:549px;
}
.image img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.image:after {
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 }
 .image:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean is not a button?

Comment: When you "hover" over the image you cannot click on it.

Comment: Why do you have an input inside anchor tag???

Comment: I am new to html and css. Is there any way you could show me the alternative.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? You want an image that has a link on it?

Comment: I would like to have an image that has a transparent hover effect that allows you to click it.

Comment: You could have just added `pointer-events: none` to the overlay and that's it. http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/cp14rbpa/11/

Comment: @Rudie Can't you see how wrong is to put input type image inside anchor tag? <button> and <input> inside a link is not allowed in HTML spec

Comment: @BojanPetkovski I didn't look at the HTML at all, sorry =) You might be right. Just for future reference: if you want to click through something, define `pointer-events`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this :)

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 726px;
  height: 549px;
}
.image a {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.image a:after {
  content: '\A';
 position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.image a:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://www.golfdigest.com.sg/files/u1/726x549-instruction.jpg" alt="Clickable" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<button>` tag instead of the `<a>` tag.  Like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/cp14rbpa/6/)